# How can I access sudo command when bin permissions are not set for execute

Tags: macos

Actually I'm new to mac.
I accidentally took away all permissions on bin directory for users. Now I cannot access any commands and moreover I cannot even access the root user on my mac, sudo command also not running. It says you don't have permission.
Can anybody please tell me how do I resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried "Repair Disk Permissions" in Disk Utility.app ?

Comment: Hey thanks man @vadian. It solved my problem. I didn't know about this utility

Comment: You're welcome. Although this function is often overestimated it could be helpful sometimes